# Missing "Toggle Editor" Button - Joomla

Tags: joomla

I have super administrator rights to a Joomla site but the "Toggle Editor" button is missing Any idea how to get it back?

Many thanks,
Steph

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this is missing?
[alt text http://www.toughtomato.com/websites/test/images/screenshots/screenshot1.png](http://www.toughtomato.com/websites/test/images/screenshots/screenshot1.png)

If not then please could you be specific as to where this "Toggle Editor" button is meant to exist.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the button below the article in the article editor
http://www.stephburningham.com/toggleeditor.jpg

Comment: What Joomla version are you using? And what editor are you using? Is it TinyMCE by any chance?